# I want to open URL with webview, but when I tried to login in that site, I can't login

Tags: android, webview

When I tried to login it shows a popup window and asking for email and password
when I entered my correct email and password and click on login it doesn't redirect to my account it only shows the same page

this is my `MainActivity`
you can also download my application for better understanding my problems https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.bidforx.bidforx

use email: anup.gorai.9835@gmail.com
password:78907890

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppRate.with(this)
                .setInstallDays(0)
                .setLaunchTimes(3)
                .setRemindInterval(0)
                .monitor();

        AppRate.showRateDialogIfMeetsConditions(this);


        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo(

        ));

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://bidforx.com");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21){
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView,true);
        }else{    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);}

        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody="Add World   ";
                String shareSub="Download the BidForx App and Buy everthing in 1% Download the App now https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.bidforx.bidforx";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareSub);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent,"Share using"));




            }
        });
    }
    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }
    private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    // on back pressed
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: hello, I can't log in with your email ID/password, and I can't register because my telephone number is not 10 digit...

Comment: you can login with web browser only

Answer (score 0):

When I try to login, I am getting an error

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null", source: https://bidforx.com/js/login.js (2)`

There must be some problem in `login.js` line 2. In line 2 you try to call `localStorage`, and somehow you can login with browser but not with app.

I haven't tried it yet but you should allow WebView to use HTML5 local storage feature first and see if you can login with app.

`webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

and I think you should do the item checking like this:

```
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty("username")) {
    //
}
```

in order to prevent `TypeError`